# Dropdown box changes two images

Tags: javascript, html, select, html-select

I have a project where I have a dropdown box that selects a live stream of a traffic camera. I have this part working. However as this selection is made from the dropdown box a map image needs to be displayed at the same time as the camera stream is displayed. This is my problem.

This is what I have so far. My questions is can I attach a second image link to each option value so when each selection is made it displays the two side by side instead of the one which it currently is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Edit: This image explains the outcome visually that I am attempting to achieve - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVzDn.jpg

```
<iframe src="http://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zqYRscs82GEY.kUSSEtK8gKbg" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

That is an example of the embedded map code that I am trying to dispaly with the camera streams

```
<html>
<body>

<img id="imageToSwap" src="http://deladream.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/1984.jpg" />

<br/><br/>

<select id="dd" onChange="swapImage()">
<option value="http://deladream.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/1984.jpg">None Selected</option>
<option value="http://131940.qld.gov.au/DMR.Controls/WebCams/DisplayImage.ashx?FilePath=Metropolitan/Upper_MtGravatt_Pac_Mwy_Nth.jpg&35170044">Upper Mount Gravatt - Pacific Motorway and Klumpp Road (North)</option>
<option value="http://131940.qld.gov.au/DMR.Controls/WebCams/DisplayImage.ashx?FilePath=\Metropolitan\MRMETRO-1224.jpg&78465240">Kenmore - Moggill Road - Kenmore Road (East)</option>
<option value="http://131940.qld.gov.au/DMR.Controls/WebCams/DisplayImage.ashx?FilePath=\Metropolitan\MRMETRO-1213.jpg&2039636175">Chermside - Gympie Road - Webster Road (South-East)</option>
<option value="http://131940.qld.gov.au//DMR.Controls/WebCams/DisplayImage.ashx?FilePath=\Metropolitan\MRMETRO-1214.jpg&2144911343">Woolloongabba - Pacific Motorway</option>
<option value="http://131940.qld.gov.au//DMR.Controls/WebCams/DisplayImage.ashx?FilePath=\Metropolitan\MRMETRO-1458.jpg&1568524335">Archerfield - Beaudesert Road and Granard Road (East)</option>
<option value="http://www.cctv.com/Library/dcs_tag.js">Chinese Pandas</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("dd");
    image.src = dropd.value;    
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you want to have 2 images showing the same image

Comment: I want to display two images side by side with the one selection. 

http://imgur.com/TKlN8i0

this shows exactly the outcome im after. My code currently displays only the camera stream

Answer (score 0):

Load your images at run time by new Image(); object

EG:

```
function loadAllPreImages(){
images = new Array();
images[0]="images/resort.jpg"
images[1]="images/accomodation.jpg"
images[2]="images/weekendgetaways.jpg"
images[3]="images/domesticvacation.jpg"
images[4]="images/internationalvacation.jpg"
images[5]="images/Beauty.jpg"
images[6]="images/Food.jpg"
images[7]="images/Entertainment.jpg"
images[8]="images/Health.jpg"
images[9]="images/Services.jpg"
var i = 0;
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{   imageelmentObj = new Image();
    images[i] = imageelmentObj.src=images[i];
}
}
loadAllPreImages();
```

Comment: if you are using random code a least change / adapt it so it works in OP besides this is not what he asked

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("dd");
    image.src = dropd.value; 

    var new_image = document.createElement("img");
    new_image .setAttribute("src") = dropd.value;
    image.parentNode.appendChild(new_image);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
u can try using a map

var arr = [];
arr['http://deladream.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/1984.jpg'] = '//another image link';


//create a map with all d options..


function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var image2 = document.getElementById("image2ToSwap");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("dd");
    image.src = dropd.value;    

    image2.src=arr[dropd.value];

};
```